# Question about command checks and command argument use issue

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a question about command checks and whether it's possible to bypass command argument.
I'm making a reply command for my mail discord bot, instead of using the command `reply <user> <message>`
I would like to remove the argument user and just use `reply <message>`.

However, I need to get the user as I did when using it as a command argument. Is this possible?

Here is what I'm working on:

```
@commands.command()
@checks.is_channel_mod()
async def reply(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, message):
    """Send a message thread reply to user."""
    if not user.dm_channel:
        await user.create_dm()
    try:
        if ctx.message.channel.name == f"{user.name.lower()}{user.discriminator}":
            time = datetime.utcnow()
            msg_sent = message[:2000] or "blank"
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Moderator Reply", description=msg_sent, timestamp=time, colour=discord.Colour(0xff8100))
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Sent by {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}")
            msg = await user.dm_channel.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name} sent a reply to {user.name}.")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'Please check you have the correct channel or thread ID.')

    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send(f"Reply cannot be sent because {user.name}'s direct messages are set to private.")
    except discord.HTTPException:
        await ctx.send('I failed in sending the message.')
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f'There\'s been a problem while sending the message that\'s not of type "Forbidden" or'
                       f' "HTTPException", but {e}.')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do it like this, you can replace pass with whatever you want to happen.

```
user = ""

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global user
    if "Direct Message" in str(message.channel):
        user = message.author

@client.command()
async def reply(ctx, *, message):
    global user
    if user != "":
        pass
        return
    await ctx.send("No messages recieved")
```